# Cocos2D iPad Vector Sprites/Spritesheet creation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to load vector graphics into the iPad using cocos(or some other method) as sprites or sprite sheets but leaving the images as vectors and not textures? The reason being is we have an animation that is just way way too big to load in as a texture so we want to scale it down using a vector image.

If this isn't the right way to do this then maybe another suggestion?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d is designed around sprites, so I don't think there is anything built in. The best solution that I can think of is to create a custom 'CCNode' and override the 'draw' method. Then you could use custom OpenGL calls to draw your vectors. Someone may have already created a class you can use, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: ah kk, I'll take a look and see if anyone has already written this. It would be a pain to write. Thanks!